# Is it possible to make a encrypted Zip file unhackable

Tags: passwords, compression, zip, archiving

I want to encrypt a Zip file. But I'm not sure it can be safe because I’ve found some tips about how to recover a .Zip with forgotten password with iSumsoft or NSIS in this article: “[How to Open Password-Protected ZIP File without Password](https://www.isumsoft.com/rar-zip/how-to-open-password-protected-zip-file-without-password.html)”

So is it possible to make an encrypted Zip unhackable (in a lifetime) or is there another compression/archiving tool that can’t be hacked the way encrypted Zip files can?

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/file-and-disk-encryption-tools-for-linux/ could be a useful read.

Comment: There's nothing unhackable, given enough time and processing power. But you can make secure enough with a complex password that it would take millions of years with the current computational power to brute-force it.

Comment: That's what I need. Unhackable in a lifetime.

Comment: As @GabrielaGarcia indicated. It's not possible (given enough time). Best bet; make a very long password, with meta/alpha/numeric characters in it. This method won't make it *impossible*. But it will *hopefully* make it more work than it seems worth, to bother. Good luck! :)

Comment: Your question cannot be answered definitively. No one here has infinite knowledge of all possible exploits against ZIP files that exist now or could be discovered in the future. Such knowledge is required to say for certain whether something is able to be secured for a lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[GabrielaGarcia](https://superuser.com/users/931000/gabrielagarcia) stated - nothing is unhackable given enough time, processing power, and desire. The methods in the link you provided are [brute force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack) and [magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic), apparently - though the "magic" NSIS supposedly employs to ***extract*** your files doesn't specifically say that it will also ***decrypt*** them - so whether or not an attacker would come away with anything usable would need to be tested. There's a good chance that encrypting your files and then zipping your archive into a [Self Extracting Executable via a tool like 7-zip](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/127113-create-self-extracting-executable-file-in-7-zip) may also bypass whatever dark magics tools like NSIS may harness.

At the end of the day, all we can really do is follow best practices when encrypting in conjunction with choosing a complex password, a [soft token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_token), or a [hard token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token) of some sort so that your encryption is backed up by two-factor authentication. As always - one of the best ways to keep your files (encrypted or not) safe is to limit access to them; if it's something you really don't want someone to get their hands on, you could take it a step further and put them on an external drive, and then encrypt the drive with a tool like [BitLocker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker).